# Edit bootstrap-sass gem in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 on rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3p194.

I want to override the default container width and the span width.

Comment: Well, good luck! Try something first, post your code and ask for help. Don't ask for the solution without trying, we are not doing the job instead of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit the gem.

Create a `bootstrap_override.css.scss` file in stylesheets folder:

```
@import 'bootstrap';

.container {
  // Your own rules
}

.span[n] {

}
```

You can override any style because you are adding bootstrap before yours. That's the way CSS  works.

Comment: yea this is one way too

Answer (score 0):

1) gem install gemedit

2) gem edit -e subl bootstrap-sass

3) Done.

Comment: I don't think he meant to edit the gem itself. This is not good practice as the changes won't flow across different machines or gemsets

Comment: yes but i think the span width is dependent on the container width right ? so if the container width is modified the spans are adjusted automatically